# Drupal 7 + SimpleSAMLphp + simplesamlphp_auth module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, single-sign-on, simplesamlphp

I have a site on a Drupal 7 and I need to add some SSO functionality. So I configured SimpleSAMLphp and installed the simplesamlphp_auth module.

The problem is the module just swaps the links to login form with its own (/saml_login). And I kinda want it to use the old login form to have seamless experience because it's so modal, beautiful and such.
Could someone maybe explain to me how it can be achieved? Or am I missing something and completely do not understand how IDPs and SPs work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to login in user/login.

If you want to disable the login at saml_login you can unset this with hook_menu_alter, disabling the route "saml_login" like this:

```
unset($items['saml_login']);
```

Or modifiying it's access:

```
$items['saml_login']['access callback'] = false;
```

Keep in mind that simplesamlphp_auth is an example module, so you should build your own module from this code and adjust it to your needs.

Hope that helps.

PD: if you need more details just tell me.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Unfortunately I am not able to use user/login using service provider credentials. So I can login with user/login URL only with Drupal credentials. If I want to use my SSO credentials to login I need to go to /saml_login page and it will redirect me to IDP page.
I need to use my Drupal login form to login users having either SSO or Drupal creds.

Comment: An alternative that doesn't use simplesamlphp, instead php-saml:
https://github.com/onelogin/drupal-saml